# Command to replace single space with tabs in a text file

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

So i have a text file and the problem is that both spaces and tabs are used to separate column values which is causing me a lot of issue due to the inconsistency. For example:

```
ID Name    Class Time
1 Johnson  5-D 6pm
         .
         .
         .
```

As you can see in the example, both **ID and Name are separated by single space** while **Name and Class are separated by a tab.**

How do i write a sed command to **replace all single space in the text file with a tab?** I would want a new text file generated looking something like:

```
ID      Name      Class     Time
1       Johnson   5-D        6pm
```

The alignment doesn't matter at this point, i just want to replace the single space with tab.

**Edit: awk script is welcomed too**

Comment: can you add what you've tried as well? if you need resources to get started with `sed`, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Comment: have a look at `man unexpand`

Comment: For the record: in the text sample above there's no tab characters at all at this stage.

Comment: Can any of your fields contain a blank or a tab?

Comment: @tink SO has an unfortunate habit of turning tabs into spaces when rendering markdown. Makes providing sample TSV data a pain.

Comment: @Shawn - that's **ugh**ly =} ... thanks for the pointer, I never noticed it before (but then, I don't use `TAB`s, either.)

Answer (score 4):

With `tr`:

```
 tr ' ' '\t' <inputfile >outputfile
```

This replaces each space character with a tab.

If you should need this, you can also replace a sequence of multiple spaces with one tab using

```
 tr -s ' ' '\t' <inputfile >outputfile
```

Comment: `tr` is the right tool but just beware of the 2nd command as it'll remove empty fields that are separated by blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `column` function:

```
column -t file
```

From `man column`:

> ```
> -t   Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table. Columns are
>      delimited with whitespace, by default, or with the characters supplied using the -s
>      option. Useful for pretty-printing displays.
> ```

Comment: it's not working. I cannot assume that all columns are separated by space. Name and Class are separated by tab not space.

Comment: @Maxx as the documentation says `Columns are delimited with whitespace` and "whitespace" includes both tabs and blanks (a "blank" is the real term what you have so far been referring to as a "space"). So if "it's not working" then it's not because of there being blanks and tabs as the separators. The real problem with this command is that it won't separate the data by tabs as you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job `sed -i -e 's/\s/\t/g' filename.txt`.

Comment: Perhaps use `y/\s/\t/` instead of `s/\s/\t/g`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` to get its advanced regular expressions (In particular lookbehind and lookahead assertations to match a single space with no other whitespace on either side):

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<=\S) (?=\S)/\t/g' input.txt
```

Comment: I don't know Perl, but does your regex does not match an individual space at the beginning or end of the string. Do you want  `/(?<! ) (?! )/`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm not going to worry about things like that unless OP says their data has empty fields.